# Opening an Native ios App inside an Another App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have this idiotic Question .

1. Is there any way open an another ios Application inside a view controller of a app.
2. I know we can open a another Ios app if we have url schema and the calling application goes to background and called application goes to background.

Is there any way ?? i just got a dream ,so am asking can we do it??

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it with the iPhone SDK. You can do this though by using Private APIs.

Comment: Third party api ...can you be precise ...can you give me resource or links i cannot find them...

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work on jailbroken devices.

But if you want to call native social apps like facebook or twitter you should use this code.
It works and apple approves it.

```
NSURL *fbNativeAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"];

    if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbNativeAppURL])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbNativeAppURL];
    }
```

or

```
NSURL *twNativeAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"];

    if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twNativeAppURL])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twNativeAppURL];
    }
```

Comment: This is opens twitter or facebook pushing my original app into the back ground i guess..